# userChanges stream in Flutter Fire does not stream profile changes

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

According to [FlutterFire docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html), userChanges should stream any changes to user profile in Firebase. I added the following code to a screen:

```dart
class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  UserInfo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {
  FirebaseUser _user;
  StreamSubscriber _userChnages;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    _userChanges = FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
      setState(() {
        _user = user;
      })
    })
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Text(_user?.email ?? "No user"),
    );
  }
}
```

When I make changes outside the app (for example new user verifies email address or I change their displayName in backend) the stream never fetches those changes and the callback of `.listen()` is never run.

Comment: How long did you wait after making the change? It may take up to an hour after the change is made to the profile on the server before that change is detected on other clients.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on how fast the changes propagate to client, but to me "stream" should mean almost immediate. I waited long enough for the token to expire and idotken refresh to fire the callback anyway.

Comment: As said "It may take up to an hour after...". Did you wait for an hour? Did the changes show up then? If you don't want to wait, you can also sign the user out and in again, or force a refresh of their token with: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html

Comment: idToken expires and auto refreshes in an hour so yes waiting for an hour token refresh will trigger the callback. But this is the effect of token expiration not profile changes propagation to clients. There is no way to refresh (user.reload()) because the event comes from outside the application (user followed email verification link in browser). Maybe the docs description of the method is misleading?

Comment: well https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3461

Comment: If you want the client to pick up the changes before it automatically refreshes the ID token, have a lookk at the flow described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client and https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime (different tool, but a much more verbose explanation of essentially the same process).

Answer (score 0):

```
userChanges() notify these cases;
```

1. Login
2. Logout

Any properties that you save on Firestore or Real-time Database  (like fullName) does not appear and reaching on FirebaseAuth service.

You can listen firestore or rtdb document for listen user document changes.

You can listen userChanges for login logout

Comment: displayName, email, phoneNumber, photoUrl, EmailVerified are all properties of the auth user profile. They're not saved externally in Firestore. Also according to documentation of userChanges "It provides events on all user changes, such as when credentials are linked, unlinked and when updates to the user profile are made."